# Pasting data with a specific word from worksheet 2 under data from worksheet 1

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

So I'm trying to have the data from worksheet 2 pasted under the data from worksheet 1 if it has the word "New" in column A.

I have this code:

```
Sub CopyRows()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim bottomL As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim c As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    bottomL = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1

    For Each c In ws2.Range("A1:A" & bottomL)
        If c.Value = "New" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Range("A" & x)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

But it keeps pasting over the data from worksheet 1 from the top down instead of pasting in the next available blank spot below.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: in ws1.Range("A" & x) value of X is 1 that is why it keeps pasting over the data from worksheet 1 from the top down instead of pasting in the next available blank spot below.

Comment: You don't need to use x, just paste to the next row.
`c.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `x` as the last row of the first worksheet and then increment it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim bottomL As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim c As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)
    bottomL = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = x + 1

    For Each c In ws2.Range("A1:A" & bottomL)
        If c.Value = "New" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Range("A" & x)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are iterating `x` from 1 every time. To paste in the next available row - you need to calculate lastrow of sheet 1 similar to your calculation of `bottomL`.

`x = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`